# Xamarin Form passing parameters between page keep a hard link to it

Tags: xamarin.forms

I try the new Shell of Xamarin Form 4 for a small project.
I have a list of order, then someone chooses an order and start picking some inventory for this order with barcode. To be simple, I use 2 views and 2 viewmodel. 
The process is:
 1. User select an order the click a button "pickup"
 2. I use ViewModelLocator (TinyIoc) to resolve the correct ViewModel of the pickup view
 3. I call Initialize on the new ViewModel and pass some parameters needed. Like a list of items needed to be pickup.
 4. Open the view in modal state.

I don't understand that if I change some qty in the list I pass on the second viewmodel, then hit the back button (modal view close). The quantity changed is now in the original viewmodel. How this is possible? I was thinking that passing parameter to a function do not share the same variable but just copy it??

Viewmodel of the first view (look at the Initialize function the List passed and the JobEnCours object)

```
    private async Task GoPickup()
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
        {
            if (this.CodeJob != null && this.CodeJob != "")
            {
                this.IsBusy = true;

                PrepChariotSP3ViewModel vm = ViewModelLocator.Resolve<PrepChariotSP3ViewModel>();
                await vm.InitializeAsync(this._jobEnCours, this.ComposantesPick.ToList()) ;

                await Shell.Current.Navigation.PushAsync(new PrepChariotSP3Page(vm));
                this.IsBusy = false;
            }
        });
    }
```

the the Initialize code on the second Viewmodel (look I set the JobEnCours.Description=Test)

```
    public async Task InitialiseAsync(Job jobEnCours, List<ComposantePick> composantePick)
    {
        Title = "Ceuillette: " + jobEnCours.CodeProd;
        this._jobEnCours = jobEnCours;
        this.ComposantesPick = new ItemsChangeObservableCollection<ComposantePick>();

        foreach(ComposantePick c in composantePick)
        {
            this.ComposantesPick.Add(c);
        }

        jobEnCours.Description = "test";
```

So, If I do the back button, then in the first VM the JobEnCours.Description is now set to "test" how this is possible?!
Any idea?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/passing-reference-type-parameters

Comment: OMG, I was not aware of that. I was thinking that the ref keyword is mendatory for this kind of beaviours. So basically, object and array pass to another object function are by 'refence' until I use the keyword new to create an new local copy? (exept if I add the ref keyword)

Comment: Classes are always passed around as references. Structs are passed by copy. Basic types copy as well. You use the ref keyword to make a type that is usually copied to a reference behavior. So you can use ref keyword on struct and basic types.